# How do i convert Xaml to Rtf in silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, rtf

I would like to know how to convert Xaml to Rtf in silverlight.

I am working on RichTextBox and i have the Xaml in hand and i would like to convert it to rtf and save it to the DB.

so how do I convert Xaml to Rtf in Silverlight? (`TextRange` doesn't work in Silverlight)

Comment: Can you load the XAML and read it back as RTF?

Comment: You mean the FlowDocuments generated by WPF's RichTextBox? Is HTML an option, too?

Comment: @Botz3000: no WPF please just Silverlight, many WPF features don't work in Silverlight :(

Comment: @Gabe: i have the Xaml as text/string yes and now i need to convert it to rtf

Comment: I don't think the Silverlight RTB uses RTF. It sounds like you're saving RTF on a server, so can you send the XAML to the server and use a WPF RTB on the server to load the XAML and read out the RTF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Gabe:The WPF RTB does NOT support all the classes defined in SL, so if you try to convert a xaml string generated by SL RTB to a rtf string in a WPF RTB, an 
**System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException** 
exception may be thrown!

Comment: hmmm interesting isn't Silverlight subset of WPF?

Comment: @peplamb we may say SL is a simplified version of WPF, but in fact they run in totally deferent frameworks (SL-runtime and .net framework). the codes in SL are rewritten and PATTERNED ON WPF.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try NRTFTree? 
This is a .net lib which can build RTF
check it in codeplex.
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/string/nrtftree.aspx